# Can quantum fields be smeared in space (rather than spacetime)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, mathematical-physics, dirac-delta-distributions, wightman-fields

I am interested in what is known about the possibility of smearing interacting quantum fields on a Cauchy slice. This is easy to do for free fields and their conjugate momentum, and indeed this is necessary to impose the CCR's. However, in  *Local Quantum Physics* Haag makes a claim that "renormalization theory *suggests* that it is essential to smear out in both space and time, in contrast to the case of free fields... Due to the stronger singularities one cannot assume well-defined commutation relations at equal times."[Haag 1996, p.59]

I don't know what logic exactly he is drawing on here, but one can at least see that unlike a smearing in spacetime, or even a smearing on a timelike curve, spatial smearings do not *have* to map states of bounded energy to each other. It is a happy accident that spatially smeared free fields do, and since the set of states of bounded energy is typically dense in the Hilbert space, this means that they are well-defined unbounded operators. However, from abstract principles alone it's hard to rule out that this is also true for general interacting quantum field theories in the continuum - and even if it isn't, and spatial smearings *don't* preserve the set of bounded energy states, it still doesn't mean they aren't well-defined on *some* dense subset. I haven't found any further arguments in the literature, except for a remark in [Halvorson's notes on AQFT](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0602036) that Haag's claim is speculative, and no proofs are known.[Halvorson 2006, p.53]

What *is* known about this question? In particular:

- Are there concrete interacting models where the Wightman field cannot be smeared in space?
- What wisdom does rigorous causal perturbation theory suggest? If
  you adiabatically switch on an interaction in a compact region of
  spacetime, can you see at any order whether or not    the field can
  be smeared in space?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.